# Concatenate with broadcast

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following arrays:

```
a = np.array([0,1])[:,None]
b = np.array([1,2,3])

print(a)
array([[0],
       [1]])

print(b)
b = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Is there a simple way to concatenate these two arrays in a way that the latter is broadcast, in order to obtain the following?

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 3]])
```

I've seen there is [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2115) closed issue with a related question. An alternative is proposed involving `np.broadcast_arrays`, however I cannot manage to adapt it to my example. Is there some way to do this, excluding the `np.tile`/`np.concatenate` solution?

Comment: Since you wrote you could not manage to adapt, here is the answer: `np.concatenate((a, np.tile(b, (2,1))), axis=1)` IIUUC. If this is what you wanted to adapt, let me know and I will undelete my answer

Comment: Could not manage to adapt the `np.broadcast_arrays` approach. Was looking for something other than a soln with `np.tile`/ `np.concatenate`. Thanks anyways @Sheldore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1])[:,None]
b = np.array([1,2,3])
b_new = np.broadcast_to(b,(a.shape[0],b.shape[0]))
c = np.concatenate((a,b_new),axis=1)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a more general solution:

```py
def concatenate_broadcast(arrays, axis=-1):
    def broadcast(x, shape):
        shape = [*shape]  # weak copy
        shape[axis] = x.shape[axis]
        return np.broadcast_to(x, shape)

    shapes = [list(a.shape) for a in arrays]
    for s in shapes:
        s[axis] = 1

    broadcast_shape = np.broadcast(*[
            np.broadcast_to(0, s)
            for s in shapes
    ]).shape

    arrays = [broadcast(a, broadcast_shape) for a in arrays]
    return np.concatenate(arrays, axis=axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had two matrices `x` and `y` of size `(X, c1)` and `(Y, c2)` and wanted the result to be the matrix of size `(X * Y, c1 + c2)` where the rows of the result were all the concatenations of rows from `x` and rows from `y`.

I, like the original poster, was disappointed to discover that `concatenate()` would not do broadcasting for me.  I thought of using the solution above, except `X` and `Y` could potentially be large, and that solution would use a large temporary array.

I finally came up with the following:

```
    result = np.empty((x.shape[0], y.shape[0], x.shape[1] + y.shape[1]), dtype=x.dtype)
    result[...,:x.shape[0]] = x[:,None,:]
    result[...,x.shape[0]:] = y[None,:,:]
    result = result.reshape((-1, x.shape[1] + y.shape[1]))
```

I create a result array of size `(X, Y, c1 + c2)`, I broadcast in the contents of `x` and `y`, and then reshape the results to the right size.